# Compiling TypeScript with filter() thisArg

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm working on an application in Node, written in TypeScript, and I'd like to use `filter()` to filter an array of objects based on an attribute. I have a public method (`getValidObjects()`) that accepts an object (`preferred`) that has properties I'd like to match against.

In my current setup, I'm taking advantage of [`thisArg`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to set the context in my callback to the preferred object.

```
class Sample {

    _objects:Object[];
    _preferred:Object;

    constructor() {
        this._objects = [
            {
                valid: true,
                label: 'This is valid'
            },
            {
                valid: false,
                label: 'This is invalid'
            }
        ];
    }

    public getValidObjects(preferred:Object) {
        return this._objects.filter(this.filterObjects, preferred);
    }

    private filterObjects(sample:Object, index:number, array:Object[]) {
        // "this" should be the preferred object

        return this.valid == sample.valid;
    }

}

export = Sample;
```

The class ultimately does compile, but it throws an error at the end:

`error TS2339: Property 'valid' does not exist on type 'Sample'.`

It looks like the compiler chokes because it's trying to do type checking against the class with `this`. I'm not sure if this is a bug in `tsc` and it just doesn't know how to handle the `thisArg`, or if there is another way to accomplish this.

#### Additional Information

1. I'm using [typescript-require](https://github.com/eknkc/typescript-require) to `require` my modules;
2. This isn't my *exact* implementation, but it's close enough to illustrate the issue.

---

## TL;DR

How can I get `tsc` to compile my class without throwing an error when using the `filter()` `thisArg` parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error arises from the fact that you have created a class-level method `filterObjects()` and use it in another context.

TypeScript compiler doesn't know about the *intended* use of this method, it decides that you're going to use it in the `Sample` context: `sample.filterObjects()`.

You have at least 2 different options to fix this error:

1. Cast `this` to the type you have in your array:

   ```
   private filterObjects(sample:Object, index:number, array:Object[]) {
       // here, Object is your type, but it can be anything else
       // you have to cast to <any> first, because compiler may warn you
       // that Sample can not be cast directly to your type

       return (<Object><any>this).valid == sample.valid;
   }
   ```
2. Move `filterObjects()` declaration inside `getValidObjects()`:

   ```
   public getValidObjects(preferred:Object) {
       function filterObjects(sample:Object, index:number, array:Object[]) {
           return this.valid == sample.valid;
       }
       return this._objects.filter(filterObjects, preferred);
   }
   ```

I suggest the second, it's semantically better (if `filterObjects` is not `Sample`'s method, it shouldn't be on it).

Comment: Great answer. I appreciate that you provided options, with decent explanations. Went with #2 :)

Comment: Glad I was able to help!